# How to remove React MUI Select component frame

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, material-ui

I struggle with removing the frame around the `<Select>` component from React Material UI library. In the picture below, when the `<Select>` component is unselected, there is a black border/frame around it.

[image: Language Select]

The code for the described component is:

```js
<Box sx={{
                minWidth: 60,
            }}>
                <Select
                    value={this.state.lang}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    sx={{
                        outline: 0,
                        border: 0,
                        boxShadow: 'none',
                        color: '#fff',
                    }}

                >
                    <MenuItem value={'en'}>EN</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={'de'}>DE</MenuItem>
                </Select>
            </Box>
```

Any clue, what do I miss? I'd rather omit the solution where I have to style my entire `<Select/>`.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The border is on the **fieldset** tag. Set it to **'none'**

```
<Select
  ...
  sx={{ '& > fieldset': { border: 'none' } }}
>
  <MenuItem value={'en'}>EN</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={'de'}>DE</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it by `variant` prop. The default value of it is `outlined` but there are two other option `filled` and `standard`. Both of last options has no outline but bottom margin which you can manage by sx or css class.
so add `variant="filled"` or `variant="standard"` to fix it.